# I am new to C# selenium. I am trying to create log file using FileAppender in log4net.

Tags: c#, selenium, log4net

facing issue: The log file is getting created however, the log is not getting written in that log file.

Please have a look at my code below (imported all required namespaces in my program however not mentioned below in the code):-

**App.config***( .config file)*

```
<appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="enter code hereC:\Users\mtuser2\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\Log\filelog.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
</root>
```

**log4netHelper Class** *(.cs file)*

```
public static ILog GetXmlLogget(Type type)
    {
        if (_xmllogger != null)
            return _xmllogger;

        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        _xmllogger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);

        return _xmllogger;

    }
```

**UnitTestTest1.cs** *(.cs file and from this file I want to write the log)*

```
 public void TestMethod1()
    {

        ILog Logger = Log4NetHelper.GetXmlLogget(typeof(UnitTest1));

        Logger.Info("This is Info");
        Logger.Fatal("This is fatal");
        Logger.Warn("Warn");



    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the app.config, appender/file value, your file path is preceded by `ener code here`. I'm guessing that's a mistake in your copy to StackOverflow as you say the file is being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_TextWriterAppender_RequiresLayout.htm), the `FileAppender` requires a `Layout` to function. Add a `layout` element within the `appender` element of the app.config file.
For example:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```